# strpos empty/blank substring in string

Tags: php, wordpress, strpos

I have a string that is attempting to find specific resources within an API call.

The resources are levels: undergraduate, graduate, independent academic work, and "" (which supposedly means none/unassigned).

So, is simply using `strpos($level, "") !== false` acceptable when attempting to find the **""** level?

I have it set up like so, but any **""** level course is not being rendered:

```
$section = $course->{'SectionName'};
$level = $course->{'Level'};
$parent = the_parent_title();
                if($section === '01' && (
                        strpos($level, $parent) !== false 
                    ||  strpos($level, "") !== false
                    ||  strpos($level, 'Independent Academic Work') !== false
                        )
                        )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two double  quotes means an empty string.

Use `empty()` function of php.

```
if (empty($level)) {
    //....
```

Or use string comparison:

```
if ($level === "") {
    //...
```